# Moving Unified Objects

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender.
The question is that I have unified multiple objects and want to move them together. When I select one, the boundary of all objects get highlighted but only selected object starts to move.
Is it possible to move them together without selecting all objects one by one? Or there is another tool? Kindly help me in dealing such problem.

Comment: "normally" if you select multiple objects and you press "G" and move your mouse...all objects will move. But maybe you can post a screenshot of your whole screen and put it in your question? because as beginner there might be problems which "experts" don't think of. You could e.g. be in edit mode. Or you could have set "affect only origins"....and so on

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "unified"? You can parent all these objects to an empty for example, or to the main object, it will allow you to move them together more easily, or you can put them in one collection, right click on the collection and choose Select Objects, or select one of these objects in the 3D view and Shift G (Select Grouped) > Collection, etc...